# Try Catch no captura excepción

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un JTable del cual se debe seleccionar una fila para poder modificar dicho registro. Si no se selecciona una fila y se quiere modificar los datos de un registro quiero que arroje una ventana informando del error.
Para saber si existe una fila seleccionada obtengo el valor de la primera columna, la cual tiene un Numero de Identificación con el siguiente código.

```
try
{
    int dni = (int)tblPacientes.getValueAt(tblPacientes.getSelectedRow(),0);
    if(dni <= 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar un paciente de la lista", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar un paciente de la lista", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

El problema es que me arroja la excepción ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1.

En el caso de que use Exception mi mensaje de error se muestra correctamente, pero no es buena practica no usar excepciones especificas.

Deduzco que el error se produce porque mi variable "dni", al no seleccionar una fila del JTable obtiene un valor "nulo" el cual no es 0 pero desconozco como puedo comparar el valor obtenido con el deseado.

Al imprimir el stacktrace me devuelve lo siguiente

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:734)
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
    at Vista.Pacientes.btnEliminarPacienteMouseClicked(Pacientes.java:392)
    at Vista.Pacientes.access$400(Pacientes.java:12)
    at Vista.Pacientes$5.mouseClicked(Pacientes.java:120)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Me parece que el error está en otro lado. Por favor, a pesar de que muestres el mensaje, considera siempre loguear el stacktrace de la excepción. Allí en el stacktrace tendrás la información para saber dónde se lanzó el problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ . El stacktrace me imprime java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 y las lineas donde puede estar el error. Es necesario que modifique mi pregunta y agrege todo lo que me imprime? Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si tienes el stacktrace disponible, mi pregunta es ¿te indica que el ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions ocurrió dentro de la línea que tienes en el try o en otro archivo? De ser así, entonces es muy probable que estás ejecutando un código diferente al que estás viendo.

Comment: Salen varias lineas donde se puede encontrar el error. Una de ellas es donde  yo declaro la variable dni

Comment: @LucasDavid si publica el stacktrace y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que Pacientes.java:392, es decir, la línea 392 de la clase `Pacientes` es la línea que está dentro de ese bloque `try`?

Comment: Efectivamente lo es.

Comment: Tal cual deducia @LuiggiMendozaJ el error estaba en otra linea, donde tambien tenia una variable dni con el valor de la primera fila pero no estaba dentro de un try.

Comment: Tengo intriga por saber qué te devuelve (int)tblPacientes.getValueAt(tblPacientes.getSelectedRow(),0); Prueba a ponerlo dentro de un Syso (con el ToString()) para ver qué nos devuelve.
Aun así, inicializa el dni a 0 al menos, para evitarnos los errores de -1 o null.
También se me ocurre que uses isRowSelected(int row) para comprobar si la fila está seleciconada. En el peor de los casos (y siendo un poco tramposos) a lo mejor puedes trabajar modificando el model que rellena la jtable y actualizándole.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con este

```
try
{
    int dni = (int)tblPacientes.getValueAt(tblPacientes.getSelectedRow(),0);
    if(dni <= 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar un paciente de la lista", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  | ArrayStoreException | NullPointerException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ocurrio un error"+e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

mira las excepciones que son especificas para este caso así dejas de utilizar la Excepción global.

Comment: Aun así salta la excepción, por lo que probablemente como dijo Luiggi el error venga de otro lado.

Comment: No entiendo cómo es que agregando más excepciones en el catch se vaya a capturar una excepción que **ya se está manejando**.

Comment: Lo peor, no entiendo cómo alguien puede votar a favor una respuesta incorrecta.

Comment: Lo dividí en varias excepciones para dar una solución al no querer utilizar una Excepción global pero tienes que mirar como esta llegando el dato en el método que esta generando la `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ` -1 ya que no esta en tu pregunta.

Comment: creo el problema viene desde la pregunta .. primero indicas que te genera un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1` y no sabes por que pero no agregas el codigo faltante para  revisar esto... pero ademas dices que es mala practica usar la `Exception` global, entonces al final solo se puede resolver una parte de esta pregunta que es la de dividir la`Exception` global en varias **Exceptions**

Answer (score -1):

Prueba así

```
try{
    int dni = (int)tblPacientes.getValueAt(tblPacientes.getSelectedRow(),0);
    if(dni <= 0)
   {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar un paciente de la # # lista", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar un paciente de la #lista", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar un paciente de la #lista", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Claro, asi probé y funciona, pero entra en el segundo catch. Y no me gusta usar excepciones globales.

Comment: lo que sucede es que la excepcion ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException no es la correcta. debe ser nullpointerexcption.

Comment: No tiene caso utilizar dos Catch y mas que todo llamar a (Exception) dado que el Exception  es una mala practica y se sobrecargaria el metodo.

Comment: @NestorLeonelOsorioTovar aun así salta la excepción y me indica que es de ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  -1

Comment: como estas forzando la exception?

Answer (score -1):

Lo que se puede hacer es incluir la comparación contra el null en el if.

```
if (dni == null || dni <= 0)
```

O bien evitar el uso de -1.

```
if (tblPacientes.getSelectedRow() == -1 || dni <= 0)
```

Comment: No puedo comparar un int con un null, y aun así comparando la fila con -1 salta la excepción.

Comment: habría que agregar el if antes del getValueAt   así: int dni = 0; if (tblPacientes.getSelectedRow() != -1) {  dni = (int)tblPacientes.getValueAt(tblPacientes.getSelectedRow(),0); } else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar un paciente de la lista", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }